# Is there any way to use haml file with Watir

Tags: ruby, cucumber, haml, watir

I want to see the test result in a html file,  but I don't know if I can use haml to code the test results.  If there is any possible solution, please intimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question doesn't say what you are using to do your testing, but based on the tags I'm going to assume you are using cucumber to express and run your tests, and Watir to drive a browser within the test steps.

If that is correct then I do not know of a way to get output in HAML format..

Cucumber *does* offer the option to output the test results in HTML.  That can be specified in the defaults file for cucumber, or from the command line.  To tell cucumber to generate results in HTML format you normally need two switches on the command line, one `-f html` to specify the format of the output as html, then `-o results.html` to specify the filename for the output.

```
cucumber -f html -o results.html
```

If you are new to cucumber I **strongly recommend** purchasing and reading *The Cucumber Book* it's the best way I know of to get off to a good start and avoid some of the common pitfalls when using the tool.

Comment: Thank You.You assumption is correct.Is it possible to edit the html coming along with cucumber.

Comment: Well it is open source, so it's possible to do just about anything if you want to fork the code and modify things.  If you are serious about making changes to the HTML results formatter, I'd ask in the cucumber google group.   The other option might be to use a standard format like JUNIT (another option cucumber supports) and then write something to parse the resulting XML and transform it into a report in the format you prefer.    just a question of what use of your time is more valuable, creating tests, or pretty output from the tests.